# How does pushd work?

Tags: bash, upgrade, for, syntax, pushd

In Ubuntu 16.04 with Bash I had a problem when I didn't have a convenient way to upgrade all my WordPress components (core, translations, theme, plugin) and I used the following code to solve it:

```
cat <<-EOF > /etc/cron.daily/cron_daily
    #!/bin/bash
    drt="/var/www/html"
    for dir in "$drt/*/"; do
        if pushd "$dir"; then
            wp plugin update --all --allow-root
            wp core update --allow-root
            wp language core update --allow-root
            wp theme update --all --allow-root
            rse
        popd
        fi
    done
EOF
```

What I'd like to ask is actually comprised of these questions:

1. How does the `dir` variable resembles the asterisk (`*`) coming a little bit after it in the same line (how is the Bash interpreter knows that `dir` represents each directory inside `/var/www/html`?
2. How does the `pushd`-`popd` sequence(?) works here? I understand it to "if you are inside $dir which resembles each iteration of the for loop, do stuff".

Comment: Not clear to me what you are asking. `drt` is set somewhere (apparently to `/var/www/html/`), and `$drt/*` simply expands to everything in that directory. With `pushd` you try to enter the directory, and if that works, you do some stuff, and with `popd` you return to your previous directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the dir variable resembles the asterisk (`*`) coming a little bit after it in the same line (how is the Bash interpreter knows that `$dir` [iteratively] represents each directory inside `/var/www/html/`?

That's just how Bash **shell globs** work/behave, but you are mistaken about one thing: `dir/*` is a glob which includes *all files* within `dir`, not just all directories: in a POSIX environment, directories are a [file type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types), but in this case only directories are relevant to the for loop and the subsequent `pushd`-`popd` pair.

> How does the `pushd`-`popd` sequence(?) works here? I understand it to "if you are inside `$dir` which resembles each iteration of the for loop, do stuff".

`pushd` and `popd` are a pair of tools that work with a data structure known as a "stack".  Picture a spring-loaded dispenser, like a [Pez dispenser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qX5GRPcUZc).

If you *push* an item onto a stack, you are storing it for later use, like pushing one 'pill' into the top of the Pez dispenser.

If you *pop* an item from a stack, you are taking it out for use or reference.  This removes it from the stack.

Take a look at this behavior for a simple example of how `pushd` and `popd` work:

```
$ pwd
/home/myuser
$ pushd /etc
/etc ~
$ pwd
/etc
$ pushd /usr/local
/usr/local /etc ~
$ pwd
/usr/local
$ popd
/etc ~
$ pwd
/etc
$ popd
~
$ pwd
/home/myuser
```

Your `for` loop basically works by saying *if* I can push this directory onto the directory stack, then that means firstly that the directory now exists, and secondly that that directory is now the current working directory.  It will proceed to do the work, and then `popd` to go back to wherever it had been before, and then run the next iteration of the loop.