# Are if-fi segments necessary when iterating on a pushd-popd directory list?

Tags: shell-script, syntax, control-flow, pushd

I use the following code which is part of [this script](https://github.com/bendqh/ulcwe/blob/master/conf_cron.sh) that I use to update my WordPress websites:

```
#!/bin/bash
drt="/var/www/html"
for dir in ${drt}/*/; do
    if pushd "$dir"; then
        wp plugin update --all --allow-root
        wp core update --allow-root
        wp language core update --allow-root
        wp theme update --all --allow-root
    popd
    fi
done
```

I learned of the specific `pushd`-`popd` pattern used in this code when I searched for a way to update all my WordPress instances in one go.

It's unclear to me why this code includes an `if-fi` segment.

### My question

Can I change the syntax somehow so that I'll have basically the same pattern but without an `if-fi` segment?

For example, instead this:

```
if pushd "$dir";
popd
    commands
fi
```

I'll have something like this pseudocode:

```
pushd "$dir";
    commands
popd
```

### Why I ask this

I can imagine how we would tell the computer something like this, without an `if-fi` statement (pseudocode):

```
for dir in ${drt}/*; do pushd "$drt"; then
    commands
popd
```

---

### Notes

1. You might want to include a different approach in your answer (i.e without `pushd`-`popd` at all).
2. [A related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430220/how-does-pushd-work).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [what @Olorin wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438619/3645) I think there might be a couple misunderstandings here. First, `for y in ${x}/*; do pushd "$y"; then` results in

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

---

Second, **the indentation may be misleading you** with regards to what is actually happening. Take this properly formatted version of the original code:

```
for y in ${x}/*/
do
    if pushd "$y"
    then
        command1
        command2
        popd
    fi
done
```

In other words, *all of* `command1`, `command2` and `popd` run only if the initial `pushd` succeeded. If you instead wrote

```
for y in ${x}/*/
do
    pushd "$y"
    command1
    command2
    popd
done
```

and there was no `errexit` guard in place, a failing `pushd` or `popd` would not affect the rest of the script. This could result in running `command1` and `command2` in the wrong directory and then possibly popping back to another directory *unrelated to this code.* This could have disastrous consequences.

---

Finally I would argue that **`pushd` + commands + `popd` is an anti-pattern** because it adds more context (and therefore cognitive overhead and risk) to a language where complex context is already a massive problem. The most common way to work around this is to pass the path (ideally absolute) to the commands, like this:

```
for y in "$x"/*/
do
    command1 "$y"
    command2 "$y"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if the `pushd` fails? If the commands are to be run in those directories, it is obvious that there should be a check to see if `pushd` succeeded before proceeding with the commands.

Comment: Why not just give an error like `pushd cannot access the collection (directory)` and be done with it?

Comment: The error is given, but... Be done with what? The `pushd` command? That iteration of the loop? The loop itself? The script? The OS session?

Comment: Be done with both the loop and the `pushd` command.

Comment: If that's the case, you can just use `pushd "$dir" || break`.

Comment: No need to update after edit with ` "$dir" || break`?

Comment: -1 | For you provide no details in your answer.

Comment: @Vlastimil details of?

Comment: @Olorin please share your thoughts on what I commented.

Comment: @user9303970 I don't see an edit with `"$dir" || break` anywhere, so I don't know what I'm expected to share my thoughts on.

Comment: @Olorin as you know, you wrote `If that's the case, you can just use pushd "$dir" || break` and I replied; I asked for your thoughts just on my replies.

Answer (score 1):

Using an if is a reasonable protection against a failure to change directory.

This code will execute the commands in the parent directory if the directory is not executable (no x permision).

```
#!/bin/bash
drt="/var/www/html"

for     dir in "${drt}"/*/
do      pushd "$dir"
        pwd
        popd
done
```

Build a couple of directories, change owner and permissions :

```
$ mkdir -p /var/www/html/{one,two}
$ sudo chown user:user /var/www/html/{one,two}
$ sudo chmod o-x /var/www/html/two
$ ./script
/var/www/html/one ~/temp
/var/www/html/one
~/temp
./script: line 5: pushd: ./var/www/html/two/: Permission denied
~/temp
./script: line 7: popd: directory stack empty
```

The command pushd emited an error, but the command pwd was executed in the ~/temp directory (note the value of ~/temp printed just after the error). That is a clear risk of doing the wrong thing. Compare with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    drt="./var/www/html"

    for     dir in "${drt}"/*/
    do      if     pushd "$dir" 2>/dev/null
            then
                   pwd
                   popd
            fi
    done
```

The new script executed:

```
$ ./script
/var/www/html/one ~/temp
/var/www/html/one
~/temp
```

Or even better:

```
#!/bin/bash
drt="./var/www/html"

for     dir in "${drt}"/*/
do      if     pushd "$dir" 2>/dev/null
        then
               pwd
               popd
        else
                echo "Failed to change to dir=$dir" >&2
                exit 7
        fi
done
```

Which, on execution, will print:

```
$ ./script
/var/www/html/one ~/temp
/var/www/html/one
~/temp
Failed to change to dir=/var/www/html/two/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a `*/` glob, the shell might do the permission check for you if you use `*/.` instead.

```
$ mkdir x y z
$ chmod -x y
$ echo */
x/ y/ z/
$ echo */.
x/. z/.
```

That way it should be a lot less likely for `pushd` to fail. However this could also be considered bad style, as that code does not really make clear that `*/.` has such an intention. With `if` the intention is obvious: make sure it succeeds, or else.

Always checking every single command for errors would be the right thing to do in general. So do it if it can be done easily and without convoluting your code too much.

However it is, unfortunately, also *normal* to not check every single command for errors and just hope/trust things will work as intended most of the time. A lot of shell scripts are meant to be simple helpers and quick hacks only.

Adding a check for every possiblity AND write code to handle each possible error in a sane manner, would quickly become convoluted and unreadable. Code readability is important, too.

`popd` can fail in some (obscure) cases too. Someone renamed the directory? Too bad. Nobody checks for these things because it's not worth it. *shrugs*

If you do not modify any variables inside that loop of yours, you could do directory your switches in subshells as opposed to pushd/popd. Each subshell has its own working directory while the parent shell keeps theirs. But if you recurse deeply it will give you a subprocess hell instead of a stack of subdirs to keep track of.

Working with absolute paths throughout is sometimes also an option.

Answer (score 1):

With gnu-find, you may do:

```
find ${drt} -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir command1 ";" -execdir command2 ";"
```

Note that not every find implementation has an -execdir option.